# Can’t build my app with release flag

Tags: android, angular, webpack, nativescript

I use **webpack** for the build of my app (with angular), the command: `npm run build-android-bundle - uglify` works very well, but when I use the flag **--release** ( npm run build-android-bundle -- --release --keyStorePath ~/path/to/keystore --keyStorePassword your-pass --keyStoreAlias your-alias --keyStoreAliasPassword your-alias-pass) an error occurs here is its content:

```
    Running full build
        ~/platforms/android/src/F0/AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31 Error:
            Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
            is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
            Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processF0F1F2F3ReleaseManifest'.
    > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:design:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
            is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
            Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.  
Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1
```

i want help please !!

my build.gradle file:

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.android.application"

def metadataParams = new LinkedList <String> ()
def allJarPaths = new LinkedList <String> ()
def configStage = "\tconfig phase: "
def nodeModulesDir = "../../node_modules/"
def dependenciesJson = file("dependencies.json")

// the build script will not work with previous versions of the CLI (3.1 or earlier)
if (!dependenciesJson.exists()) {
    throw new BuildCancelledException("""
'dependencies.json' file not found. Check whether the NativeScript CLI has prepared the project beforehand,
and that your NativeScript version is 3.3, or a more recent one. To build an android project with the current
version of the {N} CLI install a previous version of the runtime package - 'tns platform add android@3.2'.
""")
}

def nativescriptDependencies = new JsonSlurper().parseText(dependenciesJson.text)

def packageJsonContents = [:]

def dontRunSbg = project.hasProperty("dontRunSbg");
def asbgProject = project(":asbg")
asbgProject.ext.outDir = new File("$projectDir", "src/main/java")
asbgProject.ext.jsCodeDir = new File("$projectDir", "src/main/assets/app")

def computeCompileSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("compileSdk") ? compileSdk : 23 }
def computeTargetSdkVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("targetSdk") ? targetSdk : 23 }
def computeBuildToolsVersion = { -> project.hasProperty("buildToolsVersion") ? buildToolsVersion : "25.0.2" }

project.ext.selectedBuildType = project.hasProperty("release") ? "release" : "debug"

def renameResultApks = { variant ->
    def name
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def apkDirectory = output.packageApplication.outputFile.parentFile
        def abiName = "";
        if (output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)) {
            abiName = "-" + output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI);
        }
        def apkNamePrefix = rootProject.name + "-" + variant.buildType.name + abiName
        name = apkNamePrefix + ".apk"
        output.packageApplication.outputFile = new File(apkDirectory, name);
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATIONS ///////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

def applyPluginsIncludeGradleConfigurations =  { ->
    def taskNames = project.getGradle().startParameter.taskNames

    // don't apply plugin configurations if clean is invoked
    if (taskNames && taskNames.size() > 0 && taskNames.getAt(0).equals("clean")) {
        return []
    }

    def configurationsDir = new File(projectDir, "build/configurations")
    configurationsDir.deleteDir()

    def dimensions = []
    def includes = new ArrayList<String>()
    def flavorNumber = 0

    nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
        def androidDir = file("${dep.directory}/platforms/android")
        if (!androidDir.exists()) {
            return
        }

        def packageJsonPath = file("${dep.directory}/package.json")
        def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(packageJsonPath.text)
        def pluginName = packageJson.name
        def dimensionName = sanitizeDimensionName(pluginName)

        dimensions.add(dimensionName)
        def flavor = "F${flavorNumber++}"

        def includeGradleFile = new File(androidDir, "include.gradle")
        def destinationDir = file("${configurationsDir}/${pluginName}/")
        def destinationIncludeGradleFile = file("${configurationsDir}/${pluginName}/include.gradle")

        Files.createDirectories(Paths.get(destinationDir.getAbsolutePath()))

        if (includeGradleFile.exists()) {
            println "\t + add include.gradle from ${includeGradleFile}"
            destinationIncludeGradleFile.text = modifyProductFlavorInContent(includeGradleFile.text, dimensionName, flavor)
        } else {
            println "\t + creating include.gradle for plugin ${file(dep.directory)}"
            destinationIncludeGradleFile.text = createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName)
        }

        includes.add(destinationIncludeGradleFile.getAbsolutePath());

        copyAndRenamePluginDirToFlavorName(androidDir, flavor);
    }

    includes.each {
        println "\t + applying plugin configuration from ${it}"
        apply from: it
    }

    return dimensions
}

def applyAppGradleConfiguration = { ->
    def pathToAppGradle = "$projectDir/../../app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle"
    def appGradle = file(pathToAppGradle)
    if (appGradle.exists()) {
        println "\t + applying user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}"
        apply from: pathToAppGradle
    } else {
        println "\t + couldn't load user-defined configuration from ${appGradle}. File doesn't exist."
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion computeCompileSdkVersion()
    buildToolsVersion computeBuildToolsVersion()

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion computeTargetSdkVersion()
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir "$projectDir/libs/jni"
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty("release")) {
                if (project.hasProperty("ksPath") &&
                    project.hasProperty("ksPassword") &&
                    project.hasProperty("alias") &&
                    project.hasProperty("password")) {

                    storeFile file(ksPath)
                    storePassword ksPassword
                    keyAlias alias
                    keyPassword password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        renameResultApks(variant)
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        def variantName = variant.name.capitalize()
        def compileSourcesTaskName = "compile${variantName}Sources"
        def compileSourcesTask = project.tasks.findByName(compileSourcesTaskName)

        def generateBuildConfigTask = variant.generateBuildConfig;
        generateBuildConfigTask.finalizedBy(collectAllJars)
        if(!dontRunSbg) {
            collectAllJars.finalizedBy(setProperties)
        }

        compileSourcesTask.finalizedBy(buildMetadata)

        // forces packaging of resources and assets AFTER producing metadata
        // Reference: https://github.com/NativeScript/android-runtime/issues/785

        // Ensure metadata has been built and copied in assets before packaging
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def abiName = "";
            if (output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)) {
                abiName = output.getFilter(com.android.build.OutputFile.ABI)
                def packageTask = project.tasks.findByName("package${output.name}")
                if (packageTask) {
                    packageTask.dependsOn(buildMetadata)
                }
            }
        }

        // Compile the Java sources AFTER the Java code-generation step is done
        def compileTask = project.tasks.findByName("compile${variantName}JavaWithJavac")
        if (compileTask) {
            compileTask.dependsOn("asbg:generateBindings")
        }
    }

    applyAppGradleConfiguration()

    def dimensions = applyPluginsIncludeGradleConfigurations()

    flavorDimensions(*dimensions)
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

    // used for local *.AAR files
    def pluginDependencies = nativescriptDependencies.collect { "${it.directory}/platforms/android" }
    pluginDependencies.add("libs/runtime-libs")

    flatDir {
        dirs pluginDependencies
    }
}

dependencies {
    def supportVer = "22.2.0";
    if (project.hasProperty("supportVersion")) {
        supportVer = supportVersion
    }

    compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVer"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
    debugCompile "com.android.support:design:$supportVer"

    // take all jars within the libs dir
    compile fileTree(dir: "$projectDir/libs", include: ["**/*.jar"])
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// CONFIGURATION PHASE //////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task addNativeScriptRuntimePackageDependency {
    def useV8Symbols = nativescriptDependencies.any {
        def packageJsonPath = file("${it.directory}/package.json");
        def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(packageJsonPath.text);
        return packageJson.nativescript.useV8Symbols;
    }

    def runtime = useV8Symbols ? "nativescript-regular" : "nativescript-optimized";
    println "\t + adding nativescript runtime package dependency: $runtime"

    project.dependencies.add("compile", [name: runtime, ext: "aar"])
}

task addDependenciesFromNativeScriptPlugins {
    nativescriptDependencies.each { dep ->
        def aarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("${dep.directory}/platforms/android"), include: ["**/*.aar"])
        aarFiles.each { aarFile ->
            def length = aarFile.name.length() - 4
            def fileName = aarFile.name[0..<length]
            println "\t + adding aar plugin dependency: " + aarFile.getAbsolutePath()
            project.dependencies.add("compile", [name: fileName, ext: "aar"])
        }

        def jarFiles = fileTree(dir: file("${dep.directory}/platforms/android"), include: ["**/*.jar"])
        jarFiles.each { jarFile ->
            println "\t + adding jar plugin dependency: " + jarFile.getAbsolutePath()
        }

        project.dependencies.add("compile", jarFiles)
    }
}

static def updateProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName, oldContent) {
    def endIndex = oldContent.length() - 1;
        def index = 0;
        def newContent = "";
        def level = -1;
        def dimensionFound = false;

        while(index <= endIndex) {
            if (level == 0 && (oldContent[index] == '"' || oldContent[index] == "'")) {
                def closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf('"', index + 1);
                if (closingQuotes == -1) {
                    closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf("'", index + 1);
                }

                index = closingQuotes + 1;
                newContent += "\"${flavor}\"";
                continue;
            }

            if (oldContent[index] == "{") {
                level++;
            }

            if (oldContent[index] == "}") {
                level--;
            }

            if (level > 0) {
                if (!dimensionFound && oldContent.indexOf("dimension", index) == index) {
                    newContent += "dimension \"${dimensionName}\"";
                    dimensionFound = true;
                    index += "dimension ".length();
                    def openingQuoutes = oldContent.indexOf('"', index);
                    if (openingQuoutes == -1) {
                        openingQuoutes = oldContent.indexOf("'", index);
                    }

                    def closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf('"', openingQuoutes + 1);
                    if (closingQuotes == -1) {
                        closingQuotes = oldContent.indexOf("'", openingQuoutes + 1);
                    }

                    index = closingQuotes + 1;
                }
            }

            newContent += oldContent[index];

            index++;
        }

        return newContent;
}

static def createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimensionName, includeAndroidContent = true) {
    if (includeAndroidContent)
    {
        def content = """
android {
    productFlavors {
        "${flavor}" {
            dimension "${dimensionName}"
        }
    }
}
"""
        return content;
    }
    else
    {
        def content = """
    productFlavors {
        "${flavor}" {
            dimension "${dimensionName}"
        }
    }
"""
      return content;
    }
}

static def sanitizeDimensionName(str) {
    return str.replaceAll(/\W/, "")
}

static def modifyProductFlavorInContent(content, dimension, flavor) {
    def indexStart = content.indexOf("productFlavors");
    def index = indexStart  + "productFlavors".length();
    def indexEnd = -1;
    def nestedOpenBracketsCount = 0;

    while (index < content.length())
    {
        // print content[index];
        if (content[index] == "}")
        {
            nestedOpenBracketsCount--;

            if (nestedOpenBracketsCount == 0)
            {
                indexEnd = index;
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (content[index] == "{")
        {
            nestedOpenBracketsCount++;
        }

        index++;
    }

    if (indexEnd != -1)
    {
        // full content of productFlavors { ... } -> the substring is parenthesis to parenthesis -> { ... }
      def oldProductFlavorsText = content.substring(indexStart, indexEnd + 1);

      def newProductFlavorsContent = updateProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimension, oldProductFlavorsText);

      return content.replace(oldProductFlavorsText, newProductFlavorsContent);
    }
    else
    {
        def androidContentExists = content.indexOf("android {") != -1;
        def newProductFlavorsContent = createProductFlavorsContent(flavor, dimension, !androidContentExists);

        if (androidContentExists)
        {
           return content.replace("android {", "android { ${newProductFlavorsContent}");
        }
        else
        {
           return "${newProductFlavorsContent} \t ${content}"
        }
    }
}

def copyFolder(source, destination) {
    if (source.isDirectory()) {
        Files.createDirectories(destination.toPath());

        def sourceFiles = source.list();

        sourceFiles.each { file ->
            def srcFile = new File(source, file);
            def destFile = new File(destination, file);

            //Recursive function call
            copyFolder(srcFile, destFile);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Copy the file content from one place to another
        def fileName = source.getName()
        def extension = fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != -1 && fileName.lastIndexOf(".") != 0 ? fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf(".") + 1) : "";
        // exclude aars from package, as we've already included it in the compile dependencies, and don't want it taking up space
        if (extension == "aar") {
            return
        }

        Files.copy(source.toPath(), destination.toPath(), java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
    }
}

def copyAndRenamePluginDirToFlavorName(directory, flavor) {
    def targetDir = file("src/${flavor}")

    copyFolder(directory, targetDir)
}

task ensureMetadataOutDir {
    def outputDir = file("$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata")
    outputDir.mkdirs()
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////// EXECUTUION PHASE /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task collectAllJars {
    description "gathers all paths to jar dependencies before building metadata with them"

    def explodedAarDir = project.buildDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/intermediates/exploded-aar/"
    def sdkPath = android.sdkDirectory.getAbsolutePath();
    def androidJar = sdkPath + "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion + "/android.jar"

    doFirst {
        configurations.compile.each { File dependencyFile ->
            logger.info("Task: collectAllJars: dependency file: " + dependencyFile.getAbsolutePath())
            allJarPaths.add(dependencyFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        allJarPaths.add(androidJar);

        def ft = fileTree(dir: explodedAarDir, include: "**/*.jar")
        ft.each { currentJarFile ->
            allJarPaths.add(currentJarFile.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        metadataParams.add("metadata-generator.jar");
        metadataParams.add("$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata");
        def jars = new LinkedList<File>()
        for (def i = 0; i < allJarPaths.size(); i++) {
            metadataParams.add(allJarPaths.get(i));
            def f = new File(allJarPaths.get(i))
            if (f.getName().endsWith(".jar")) {
                jars.add(f)
            }
        }

        asbgProject.ext.jarFiles = jars
    }
}

task buildMetadata (type: JavaExec) {
    description "builds metadata with provided jar dependencies"

    inputs.files(allJarPaths)
    inputs.dir("$buildDir/intermediates/classes")

    outputs.files("metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeNodeStream.dat", "metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeStringsStream.dat", "metadata/output/assets/metadata/treeValueStream.dat")

    doFirst {
        // get compiled classes to pass to metadata generator
        // these need to be called after the classes have compiled
        def classesDir = "$buildDir/intermediates/classes"

        def classesSubDirs = new File(classesDir).listFiles()
        def selectedBuildType = project.ext.selectedBuildType

        for (File subDir: classesSubDirs) {
            if (!subDir.getName().equals(selectedBuildType)) {
                def subDirBuildType = new File(subDir, selectedBuildType)
                if (subDirBuildType.exists()) {
                    metadataParams.add(subDirBuildType.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        }

        def classesDirBuildType = new File(classesDir, selectedBuildType)
        if (classesDirBuildType.exists()) {
            metadataParams.add(classesDirBuildType.getAbsolutePath())
        }

        workingDir "build-tools"
        main "-jar"

        logger.info("Task buildMetadata: Call metadata-generator.jar with arguments: " + metadataParams.toString().replaceAll(',', ''))
        args metadataParams.toArray()
    }

    doLast {
        copy {
            from "$projectDir/metadata/output/assets/metadata"
            into "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"
        }
    }
}

task generateTypescriptDefinitions (type: JavaExec) {
    def paramz = new ArrayList<String>();
    def includeDirs = ["com.android.support", "/platforms/" + android.compileSdkVersion]

    doFirst {
        delete "build-tools/typings"

        workingDir "build-tools"

        main "-jar"

        paramz.add("dts-generator.jar");
        paramz.add("-input");

        for (String jarPath: project.jarFiles) {
            // don't generate typings for runtime jars and classes
            if (shouldIncludeDirForTypings(jarPath, includeDirs)) {
                paramz.add(jarPath);
            }
        }

        paramz.add("-output");
        paramz.add("typings");

        logger.info("Task generateTypescriptDefinitions: Call dts-generator.jar with arguments: " + paramz.toString().replaceAll(',', ''))
        args paramz.toArray();
    }
}

generateTypescriptDefinitions.onlyIf {
    project.hasProperty("generateTypings") && Boolean.parseBoolean(project.generateTypings)
}

static def shouldIncludeDirForTypings(path, includeDirs) {
    for (String p: includeDirs) {
        if (path.indexOf(p) > -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

task copyTypings {
    doLast {
        println "Copied generated typings to application root level. Make sure to import android.d.ts in reference.d.ts"

        copy {
            from "$projectDir/build-tools/typings"
            into "$projectDir/../../"
        }
    }
}

copyTypings.onlyIf { generateTypescriptDefinitions.didWork }

task validateAppIdMatch {
    doLast {
        def packageJsonFile = new File("$projectDir/../../package.json");
        def lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");

        if (packageJsonFile.exists() && !project.hasProperty("release")) {
            String content = packageJsonFile.getText("UTF-8")
            def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
            def packageJsonMap = jsonSlurper.parseText(content)

            if (packageJsonMap.nativescript.id != android.defaultConfig.applicationId) {
                def errorMessage = "${lineSeparator}WARNING: The Application identifier is different from the one inside 'package.json' file.$lineSeparator" +
                    "NativeScript CLI might not work properly.$lineSeparator" +
                    "Update the application identifier in package.json and app.gradle so that they match.";
                logger.error(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// OPTIONAL TASKS //////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

task setProperties {
    project.ext.jarFiles = []
    doLast {
        def list = [];
        allJarPaths.each({f ->
            if(f.endsWith(".jar")) {
                list.add(f);
            }
        })
        project.jarFiles = list;
    }
}

setProperties.finalizedBy("asbg:generateBindings", generateTypescriptDefinitions)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////// EXECUTION ORDER /////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

collectAllJars.dependsOn(ensureMetadataOutDir)
buildMetadata.dependsOn(collectAllJars)
generateTypescriptDefinitions.finalizedBy(copyTypings)

task buildapk {
    //done to build only necessary apk
    if (project.hasProperty("release")) {
        dependsOn "assembleRelease"
    }
    else {
        dependsOn "assembleDebug"
    }
}

//////// custom clean ///////////
task deleteMetadata (type: Delete){
    delete "$projectDir/metadata/output", "$projectDir/src/main/assets/metadata"
}

task deleteFlavors (type: Delete){
    doLast {
        def srcDir = new File("$projectDir/src")
        srcDir.listFiles().each({ f ->
            def dirName = f.getName()
            if (dirName != "main" &&
                    dirName != "debug" &&
                    dirName != "release")   {
                delete f
            }
        })
    }
}

task deleteGeneratedBindings(type: Delete) {
    delete "$projectDir/src/main/java/com/tns/gen"
}

buildapk.finalizedBy("validateAppIdMatch");
deleteMetadata.dependsOn(":asbg:clean")
deleteFlavors.dependsOn(deleteMetadata)
deleteGeneratedBindings.dependsOn(deleteFlavors)
clean.dependsOn(deleteGeneratedBindings)
```

Comment: please add your build.gradle file! :) @tsaadi

Comment: I edited my question to add build.gradle @Jorgesys

Comment: What version of android studio are  u using?

Comment: Android Studio Version 2.3 in UBUNTU 16.04 machine

Comment: Ok when you have time you must upgrade to AS 3.0 im not pretty sure if appcompat-v7:26 will work correctly with AS 2.3, btw i have added an answer

Comment: upgaded to 3.0 but probleme persiste. the log is the some.

Answer (score 0):

The real solution is to keep all your dependencies in the same version unless you really need to have an older version. So make sure all your support libraries are at 26.0.0-alpha1 or whatever level you want.

Alternate solution:

Go to your android manifest and add this line:

tools:replace="android:value" to the metadata element. It tells android what library you want to use to build.

Comment: and how he can configure the library to use?

Comment: I don't understand your question. The libraries are there in his manifest. I don't know if these are the ones that are causing him issues though because those he set are much lower version and he is only including support design in debug builds. I'm referring to these lines: compile "com.android.support:support-v4:$supportVer"
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportVer"
    debugCompile "com.android.support:design:$supportVer"

Comment: What value i need to configure for: tools:replace="android:value"

Comment: I think its just tools:replace="android:value"

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem. triniwiz helped me, thanks to him and to you. here is [the link](https://discourse.nativescript.org/t/cant-build-my-app-with-release-flag/3693/2?u=tsaadi) to the solution. thanks again

> triniwiz
>
> So it looks like you have a couple plugins that use different version
>   of the support lib so you can try the following to lock the support
>   version it will lock it to the latest u can choose which version you
>   want the app to use also you will need to put this in the the
>   app.gradle located in /SomeApp/app/App_Resources/Android/app.gradle
>
> repositories { maven {
>               url 'https://maven.google.com'
>           } }
>
> configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.eachDependency {
>   DependencyResolveDetails details ->
>       def requested = details.requested
>       if (requested.group == 'com.android.support') {
>           if (!requested.name.startsWith("multidex")) {
>               details.useVersion '27.0.2'
>           }
>        }
>
> } }